# tengo lista de conjuntos y debo de crear una columna con sumatorio de medallas

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, diccionarios, matriz

estoy en medio de un proyecto en el cual me piden que de una lista que tiene como contenido un determinado numero de diccionarios con la informacion de los atletas de los olimpicos:

```
[{nombre:"",pais:"",medalla:"",anio:""},
 {nombre:"",pais:"",medalla:"",anio:"", .....}]
```

Y una funcion me pide retornar un diccionario en donde las llaves sean el pais que mas haya ganado mas medallas y el valor el numero de medallas ganadas. ¿Como podria realizar el contador recorriendo los paises el numero de medallas al mismo tiempo?

#### Edición

Lo he hecho así:

```
from collections import Counter 

def pais_con_mas_medallas(todos_los_atletas:list)->dict: 
    c = Counter(d["pais"] for d in todos_los_atletas if ["medalla"]!="na") 
    record = c.most_common(1)[0][1] 
    return {pais: contador for pais, contador in c.items() if contador==record}
```

Comment: Haz un diccionario vacío `d`. Recorre tu lista. Para cada pais que encuentres en tu lista, saca el número de medallas. Mira si el pais ya estaba en el diccionario `d`  (`if pais in d`). Si no estaba, añade una entrada en `d` para ese pais, con valor 0. Después suma a lo que hubiera en esa entrada el número de medallas.

Comment: lo he hecho asi from collections import Counter

def pais_con_mas_medallas(todos_los_atletas:list)->dict:
  c = Counter(d["pais"] for d in todos_los_atletas if d["medalla"]!="na")
  record = c.most_common(1)[0][1]
  return {pais: contador for pais, contador in c.items() if contador==record}

Comment: como lo ves tu , es asi como tu dices tu lo harias asi  @abulafia

Comment: p entre a stackoverflow y vi alguien que preguntaba lo mis mo que yo el mismo proyecto y vi todas las respuestas y esta decia que era la mejor pero no es algo que yo haya hecho si es la mas adecueda y entendi de lo que encontre

Comment: Ah, había entendido que debías crear un diccionario con el número de medallas ganado por cada pais, pero releyendo la pregunta veo que se trata de encontrar el pais con más medallas. En ese caso la solución con `Counter()` es correcta, pero suponía que se te pedía hacerlo usando primitivas más básicas, como diccionarios y bucles

Comment: yo no puedo hacerlo asi debo de hacerlo como tu dices  esta forma es demasiado compleja para mi y para mi proyecto pero vi que es lo mismo , intentare como tu dice que es como tengo que hacerlo y te mandare de nuevo

Answer (score 2):

Solución alternativa admitiendo duplicados:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

data = [
    {'nombre': 'a', 'pais': 'y', 'medalla': '1', 'anio': '1'},
    {'nombre': 'x', 'pais': 'z', 'medalla': '1', 'anio': '1'},
    {'nombre': 'b', 'pais': 'y', 'medalla': '1', 'anio': '1'}
]

sortkeyfn = itemgetter(1)
values = sorted([list(d.values()) for d in data], key=sortkeyfn)
```

los diccionarios preservan el orden de inserción desde Python 3.7+, por lo que `values` se dispondrá en el orden esperado. Para versiones anteriores no podrá ordenar el diccionario (deberá obtener una representación ordenada, por ejemplo mediante `collections.OrderedDict`).

`groupby` requiere que la entrada sea ordenada primero:

```
groups = [(k, sum(int(m[2]) for m in v)) for k, v in groupby(values, key=sortkeyfn)]
result = max(groups, key=itemgetter(1))
print(result)  # {'y': 2}
```